# Can we use the command "sed" to replace a string to another string that includes the character " / "?

Tags: command-line

I try to replace "_" to "/"

```
$ echo "hahahaa_the_cat_hahahaa" | sed "s/_///g"
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The substitution operator (`s/old/new/`) can take any character as a delimiter:

```
$ echo foo | sed 's|f|g|'
goo
$ echo foo | sed 'safaga'
goo
```

So just use anything that isn't `/` and you can do what you want:

```
$ echo "hahahaa_the_cat_hahahaa" | sed 's|_|/|g'
hahahaa/the/cat/hahahaa
```

Alternatively, you can escape the `/` with a `\` (write `\/`):

```
$ echo "hahahaa_the_cat_hahahaa" | sed 's/_/\//g'
hahahaa/the/cat/hahahaa
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using `/` as your delimiter in `sed` while also using it as the character to substitute.

Try using a different delimiter such as `|`:

```
$ echo "hahahaa_the_cat_hahahaa" | sed 's|_|/|g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the slash `/` character by backslash `\`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/_/\//g' <(echo 'https:__askubuntu.com')
https://askubuntu.com
```

ie. using a `\` before the "/" stops the "/" being seen as a seperator, but as a character to be translated... (*this probably isn't worded very well sorry*)